# Sharing link for WhatsApp Web version?

Tags: button, whatsapp

I placed a button on my website with a link for people to share articles on Whatsapp. The code is this and works fine:

`<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>`

But this doesn't work on the desktop version. Does anybody know the url to share text/link on the Whatsapp Web? This here: https://web.whatsapp.com

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 26):

*Note: To create a link with a pre-filled message, use this link (works only for the Whatsapp web version!)*

Example:

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=textToshare" target="_blank">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

---

*Note: you can use this link which includes a pre-filled message which will automatically appear in a chat text field (works for all platforms!)*

Example:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=textToshare" target="_blank">Share via Whatsapp API</a>
```

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=textToshare

Comment: this does not work on desktop browser: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=textToshare

Answer (score 4):

To create your own link with a pre-filled message that will automatically appear in the text field of a chat, use https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext where whatsappphonenumber is a full phone number in international format and URL-encodedtext is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.

Example: https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I%27m+interested+in+your+car+for+sale

To create a link with just a pre-filled message, use https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext

Example: https://wa.me/?text=I%27m+inquiring+about+the+apartment+listing
After clicking on the link, you will be shown a list of contacts you can send your message to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Try this..

Comment: I think your solution is ok in mobile view. For desktop I think you must use the @The Bib Boss solution. For me that solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=textToshare" target="_blank">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

This is new updated API link to share web pages or links to your whatsapp contacts.