# Share a link from my website to WhatsApp web application

Tags: html, whatsapp

I have a web application and in that, I am trying to share a link to WhatsApp web application and but not in mobile app.

I have gone through [Sharing link for WhatsApp Web version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284469/sharing-link-for-whatsapp-web-version) but no solution is provided.

Is it feasible?

What have I tried till now

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=www.google.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

This code helps me to share it via WhatsApp mobile application. Is there a way to do the same in WhatsApp web application?

Answer (score 54):

This link - will always open a browser, even if you're in mobile.

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.google.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp web</a>
```

But when using the `api.whatsapp.com` - it will try to first, open the whatsapp mobile application OR whatsapp web on desktops if exists, if not - it will open other suitable app.

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.google.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp web</a>
```

So the `api` worked best for me

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: As of 2021 October, https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.example.com does not seem to be working anymore?

UPDATE: ah there's just no styles so the offer to send the message via web is ¾ down the page, and it doesn't automatically do web.  Can anyone confirm it does work automatically on mobile?

Comment: How can I share the images as a photo on whats app from the link instead of text or image along with text message

Comment: @mlncn yes it is working on mobile.

Comment: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.google.com does not work and the url whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World! open the app if it is installed. Is there any link to open the web app in case the mobile app not installed?

Comment: @Slim have you found any way to open the web app if the mobile app is not installed yet?

Comment: @DestinyFranks I just use this url https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text which will redirect to  a page where to choose to download the app to continue or use the web app

Answer (score 21):

this work for me

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=www.google.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp web</a>
```

Comment: `web.whatsapp.com` will alway try to open the web. vs `api.whatsapp.com` which finds what's available. if there's an app ( desktop/mobile ) - it will open it instead ... just note.