# how to share my website link on whatsapp and other social medias?

Tags: php

Ok, I'm trying to add a WhatsApp share button to my website. I have the links but the problem is each link only works for one version of WhatsApp. one for the mobile version, one for the web version.

I wonder if there is any link that can work with all version of WhatsApp?

For example, telegram has this link for sharing

https://telegram.me/share/url?url=URL&text=$PostTitle

All I have to do is putting a value in place of "URL". It works for all version of the telegram. mobile and Windows.

Does WhatsApp have such a link or twitter or facebook?

Answer (score 5):

Please find below details for each,

Twitter :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=YOUR_URL">Twitter</a>
```

Facebook :

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=YOUR_URL" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Facebook</a>
```

WhatsApp :

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=YOUR_URL" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">WhatsApp</a>
```

**EDIT**

Your WhatsApp link will work for mobile but not web. To work with web when attempt to launch the WhatsApp application fails use

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YOUR_URL" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">WhatsApp</a>
```

[SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54920622/7895205) and [WhatsApp Reference](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app/?lang=en)

Comment: thanks, man. it was so helpful I just wonder if there is any way to share a text and image with the links too?

Comment: Actually, I am not aware with image sharing. I have never tried it. @rezahooshyarr I don't know why people down-voted this answer.